# MySQL+PHP: optimise ranking query and count subquery

Tags: php, mysql, count, subquery, rank

This is raw data, and want to rank them according to score (count(tbl_1.id)).

```
[tbl_1]
===========
id | name  
===========
1  | peter
2  | jane
1  | peter
2  | jane
3  | harry
3  | harry
3  | harry
3  | harry
4  | ron
```

So make temporary table (tbl_2) to count score for each id.

```
SELECT id, name, COUNT( id ) AS score
FROM tbl_1
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY score DESC;
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Then result is;

```
[tbl_2]
===================
id | name  | score
===================
3  | harry | 4
1  | peter | 2
2  | jane  | 2
4  | ron   | 1
```

Then query this;

```
SELECT v1.id, v1.name, v1.score, COUNT( v2.score ) AS rank
FROM votes v1
JOIN votes v2 ON v1.score < v2.score
OR (
v1.score = v2.score
AND v1.id = v2.id
)
GROUP BY v1.id, v1.score
ORDER BY v1.rank ASC, v1.id ASC
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Then result is;

```
==========================
id | name  | score | rank
==========================
3  | harry | 4     |  1
1  | peter | 2     |  2
2  | jane  | 2     |  2
4  | ron   | 1     |  4
```

Is it possible to do this in one transaction (query) nicely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do this in a single query.  But it's a total hairball in MySQL, because MySQL doesn't have a simple ROWNUM operation, and you need one for the rank computation.

Here's your vote query with the rank shown. The @ranka variable is used to number the rows.

```
SELECT @ranka:=@ranka+1 AS rank, id, name, score
  FROM
  (
     SELECT id, 
            name, 
            COUNT( id ) AS score
       FROM tbl_1
       GROUP BY id
       ORDER BY score DESC, id
   ) votes,
  (SELECT @ranka:=0) r
```

As you have discovered already, you need to self-join this thing to get a proper ranking (which handles ties correctly).  So, if you take your query and replace the two references to your `votes` table each with their own version of this subquery, you get what you need.

```
SELECT v1.id,
       v1.name,
       v1.score,
       COUNT( v2.score ) AS rank
  FROM (
         SELECT @ranka:=@ranka+1 AS rank,
                id,
                name,
                score
           FROM
              (
                SELECT id,
                       name,
                       COUNT( id ) AS score
                  FROM tbl_1
                 GROUP BY id
                 ORDER BY score DESC, name
               ) votes,
         (SELECT @ranka:=0) r) v1
  JOIN (
         SELECT @rankb:=@rankb+1 AS rank, 
                id, 
                name, 
                score
           FROM
              (
                SELECT id,
                       name,
                       COUNT( id ) AS score
                  FROM tbl_1
                  GROUP BY id
                  ORDER BY score DESC, name
              ) votes,
        (SELECT @rankb:=0) r) v2 
    ON (v1.score < v2.score) OR 
       (v1.score = v2.score  AND v1.id = v2.id)
 GROUP BY v1.id, v1.score
 ORDER BY v1.rank ASC, v1.id ASC
 LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Told you it's a hairball.  Notice that you need different  @ranka and @rankb variables in the two versions of the subquery that you're self-joining, to make the row numbering work correctly: these variables have connection scope, not subquery scope, in MySQL.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5350/1/0 shows this working.

**Edit:** It's far easier to do this using PostgreSQL's RANK() function.

```
SELECT name, votes, rank() over (ORDER BY votes)
  FROM (
        SELECT name, count(id) votes
          FROM tab
         GROUP BY name
       )x
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/94cca/18/0

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation and the wonderful code! I tried the former code (SELECT @a, @a := @a+1 ...) but it didn't return correct ranking on same score. Thank you very much :)

Comment: The first chunk of code is a subset of what you need to make this work.  It's the subquery that is repeated twice, taking the place of your `votes` table, in your otherwise correct query. It's OK to ACCEPT an answer on Stack Overflow if it is helpful.  Click on the green checkbox.